# update field in model using the same field with the function update() django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have for many records to update a field, I must do it with the function .update() that already comes with the ORM of Django. I need to update this field concatenating a string with the value of the same field.

I have tried using annotate, with F expression and Value. But it didn't work, because in the annotation of a field I can't seem to use the same field.

This is what I tried to do:

```py
Model.objects.all().annotate(image=Concat(Value("Path/"), F("image")))
```

I have the next model:

```
+------+-------+
| id   | image |
+------+-------+
|    1 | image1|
|    2 | image2|
|    3 | image3|
```

When updating the model, suppose I want to concatenate the string "Path/" with field image, should be something like this

```
+------+------------+
| id   | image      |
+------+------------+
|    1 | Path/image1|
|    2 | Path/image2|
|    3 | Path/image3|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look into the Django functions like Concat:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Concat
Model.objects.update(image=Concat(Value('Path/'), F('image')))
```

Comment: I've tested it in my environment and it works fine. I'm using Django 2.1. Which version of Django are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
Model.objects.update(image=Value('Path/') + F('image'))
```

`F` gives a reference to the previous value of the field

Comment: that doesn't work, because the "+" is only valid for sums, Django doesn't recognize between fields "+" to concatenate